# Custom Components in a Custom Layout in react-admin e.g. appbar, sidebar doesnt' don't show the correct theme colours for all page types

Tags: material-ui, react-admin

**What you were expecting:**

When you are dynamically pick a theme object in a custom layout based on the URL/history in react-admin resource, the correct theme is used on the every page type e.g. List, Show, Create and Edit.

**What happened instead:**

When you go to the resource listing page, the correct theme is used. But when you then navigate to any of the create/show or edit pages, the theme seems to default back to the base / primary one.

**Steps to reproduce:**

Create Custom Layout file. Overwrite the Appbar and List component (with Listbase) with custom ones too. Although I'm not sure the appbar/listbase steps are necessary.
Use the custom Layout in the Admin component.
Create some resources.
Dynamically pick a theme based on the name of the Resouce (using history).
Navigate to the listing page of the resources. They display the specific theme correctly.
Navigate to the create/show/edit pages of the resources. These, for some reason, default back to the primary theme (or primary default colours).
Related code:

At the root level code..

```
<Admin
      authProvider={AuthProvider({ awsConfig })}
      dashboard={Dashboard}
      dataProvider={graphQLProvider}
      history={history}
      layout={Layout}
      title="Home"
      loginPage={CustomLogin}
     // logoutButton={LogoutButton}
    >
 <LMSResource projection={["details"]} name="Assigment" options={{label: 'Assignments'}} create={AssignmentCreate} list={AssignmentList}
                   title="Generic" show={AssignmentShow} edit={AssignmentEdit} icon={AssignmentIcon}/>
```

In the custom Layout file (I have an array of themes to choose from that is imported from another file)

```
const Layout = ({
    children,
    dashboard,
    logout,
}) => {
    const [resource, setResource] = useState('');
    const history = useHistory();
    useEffect(() => {
          const newResource = history.location.pathname.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '').toLowerCase(); 
          if(newResource===''){
             setResource('primary');
          } else if (newResource !== resource) {
              setResource(newResource);
          }
    }, [history.location.pathname]);

    function getTheme(themes){
        let result = ''
        var i=0;

        for(i = 0; i < themes.length; i++){
            if(Object.keys(themes[i])[0] === resource){
                result = themes[i][resource];
            }
        }
        return (!result ? themes[0].primary : result );
    }

    const theme = createMuiTheme(getTheme(themes));
    const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  ...
    }));

    const classes = useStyles(theme);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const open = useSelector(state => state.admin.ui.sidebarOpen);

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <CssBaseline /> 
            <Grid container>
                <Box className={classes.sidebar} color="grey.200" borderRight={1} item md={3} lg={2} component={Grid} display={{ xs: 'none', md: 'block' }}>
                    <Grid>
                         <Logo/>
                         <SchoolText  color='textPrimary'/>
                    </Grid>
                    <TextField className={[classes.search,classes['search' + resource]]} id="outlined-basic" label="Search" variant="outlined" />
                    <Sidebar open={open} className={classes.sidebar}>               
                        <Menu logout={logout} hasDashboard={!!dashboard} />
                    </Sidebar>

                </Box>
                <Box item component={Grid} xs={12} md={9} lg={10}>
                   <AppBar title={resource} logout={logout} />
                   <Box component={Grid} className={classes.breadcrumb} display={{ xs: 'none', md: 'block' }} borderTop={1}>
                       <Breadcrumbs/>
                   </Box>
                   <main>    
                    <div className={classes.content}>
                        {children}
                    </div>
                    </main>
                </Box>    
                <Notification />
            </Grid>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}; export default Layout
```

I can post the List, Show, Create and Edit components if necessary, but I presume if one of resource components is receiving the right theme variables, then they all should?

To be clear, I mean the layout colours outside of the List, Edit, Create and Show components and in the actual Layout components i.e. the appbar background is the wrong colour, as is the sidebar etc. So how can they be right for List but wrong for Edit, Create and Show pages when it uses the same layout component for each in the resource? I don't think I have any way of controlling this?

**Environment**

React-admin version: 3.7.1
Last version that did not exhibit the issue (if applicable): n/a
React version: 17.0.2
Browser: all
Stack trace (in case of a JS error): n/a

Answer (score 0):

Sooo. Don't mess with Regexs kids, they're dangerous. The issue was related to the different URL structure of create/edit/show vs list and therefore the theme matching didn't work..